# jQuery Cookie doesn't save value

Tags: jquery, cookies, setcookie, jquery-cookie

I have jQuery Cookie Plugin and want I to set a cookie (with expires) to execute a script after x pageviews but cookie doesnt return vlaue of pageviews but return NaN.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // visited = 0
    if (visited == 3) {
        execute script
    } 
    else {
        visited++;// increase counter of visits

        // set new cookie value to match visits
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
        $.cookie('visited', visited, {expires: date});

        return false;
    }
});
```

What is the problem in my script?

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var visited = 0;
if ($.cookie('visited')) {//test if cookie exist 
  visited = $.cookie('visited');
}

    if (visited == 3) {
       //
    } 
    else {
        visited++;// increase counter of visits

        // set new cookie value to match visits
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
        $.cookie('visited', visited, {expires: 1});

        return false;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dfL94kjh/